# Internet access from friend's wifi over GSM network

Tags: android-wifi, gsm, modem, at-command

I am trying to develop this project for my coming semester. Before beginning to start I want to know is this possible or not? It is similar to Old classical Dial-Up network but very different and very unique. Although Dial-Up services are available from service providers but, I don't want to use that.

So basically I want to use my GSM phone service to call my friend and share his WiFi network. So my App should be able to..

1) Initiate a call from GSM phone (Any service provider Bell, Talus etc)

2) My friend will receive a call who also have App installed and he should be able to activate the app during the active phone line.

3) Once app is activated the app in my friend's phone it should connect the GSM modem to WIFI in his phone.

4) Once Connected My phone should also connect the WiFi modem to GSM modem so, I can channel through the data packets from my phone to my friend's phone so that I can start surfing internet using his WiFi when he is in free WiFi zone lol.

I don't want to start doing this before knowing the complexity and time. Any Help will be appreciated. If anyone would like to do it together please feel free to send me an Gmail or Skype me ON: alir2t2

Answer (score 1):

GSM is a circuit-switched, voice-optimised service, not a data service.  You mention making a "call" - this word is normally used for voice calls.  So that's the first problem.

The second problem would be getting a data connection between your phone and your friend's phone.
The snag is, that you can't make a data connection directly to someone else's phone using the GPRS/UMTS/LTE networks.  You can only make a data connection (eg a PDP context) from your phone to a server in your operator's core network.  Then you make an IP connection on top of that, to whatever websites you want.
So your friend's phone would have to be a web server, for example, and it would also have to be connected to the network.

To connect your phone with your friend's, you need a peer to peer data connection, like Bluetooth.  (There is such a system under discussion at 3GPP for emergency situations, but it hasn't been implemented yet, and it would only be short range anyway.)

Another point is, that if you have a data connection to the internet via your operator's network, why would you want to use your friend's WiFi.....